# how to write a file correctly after editing

Tags: python, encryption

say i encrypt a .doc (or any other type) file and i decrypt it later. however, i cant open it because during the decryption process, [null]s and [DC1] and other highlighted chars were not put back into the file since they are not part of the ASCII characters. how are they written in other programs that compress/encrypt/edit/etc?

im doing this in python, so normally, without editing, i can do:

```
file1 = open(file,'rb').read()
file2 = open(new_file,'wb')
file2.write(file1)
```

but this doesnt work if i encrypt and decrypt

Answer (score 4):

Nulls and DC1's and so on are **definitely** part of the ASCII character set, so I don't know what you're talking about. So, for example, consider...:

```
>>> import pyDes
>>> f = open('afile', 'w')
>>> f.write('Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\n')
>>> f.close()
>>> data = open('afile').read()
>>> encrypted = pyDes.des('mysecret').encrypt(data, padmode=pyDes.PAD_PKCS5)
>>> f = open('encryp', 'wb')
>>> f.write(encrypted)
>>> f.close()
>>> encdata = open('encryp', 'rb').read()
>>> decrypted = pyDes.des('mysecret').decrypt(encdata)
>>> decrypted
'Nel mezzo del cammin di nostra vita\n\x04\x04\x04\x04'
```

Whatever encryption you're using ([pyDes](http://twhiteman.netfirms.com/des.html) or other) isn't this exactly the kind of thing you're claiming is NOT working...?!

If you're hoping to get help diagnosing the bugs in your code, you'd better post that buggy code, rather than generic descriptions that just don't give enough info to understand your bugs.

Comment: I guess he didn't post the encryption code because he's just written it - so it can't have bugs...therefore it must be the file writing!

Answer (score 1):

What encryption are you using?
Proper encryption will also encrypt non ascii characters so they can be decrypted properly later